# Use of InstrRev

Tags: visual-basic

I am a novice Visual Basic user. I am an engineer, but I don't have much programming experience.

I recently purchased the source code for a data recovery tool. I have decided to work through it, line by line, in order to become familiar with the tool itself and VB in general. Hopefully I will be able to maintain what would otherwise be a defunct project.

After reading the "tour" guide for this forum, I am a little concerned that my questions will not be appropriate.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tour

"Don't ask about explaining, writing or debugging code."

Anyway, my first question relates to the following function.

```
Public Function GetExtension(FileName As String) As String
        Dim i1 As Long
        Dim II As Long

        For i1 = Len(FileName) To 1 Step -1
             Select Case Mid$(FileName, i1, 1)
          Case "."
                II = Len(Left$(FileName, i1))
                     GetExtension = Mid(FileName, II + 1, Len(FileName))
              Exit Function
                 Case ":", "\"
              Exit For
             End Select
        Next
End Function
```

AIUI, the above routine gets the extension from a filespec by extracting everything after the last period.

ISTM that a simpler way to achieve the same end would be by way of the InstrRev function, as follows.

```
Public Function GetExtension( FileName As String ) As String
        Dim i1 As Long
        i1 = InstrRev( FileName, "." )

        If i1 <> 0 Then
                 GetExtension = Mid(FileName, i1 + 1, Len(FileName))
        Else
                 GetExtension = ""
        End If
End Function
```

Would there be any reason why InstrRev would not be appropriate? Could it be that InstrRev was not available at the time the code was written?

My second observation is that the following statement seems redundant:

```
II = Len(Left$(FileName, i1))
```

AFAICT, ...

```
Len(Left$(FileName, i1)) = i1   for all values of i1 >= 1
```

Are questions such as this one OK? If so, then you can expect a deluge.

Comment: its fine, but if you change a function make sure you have unit tests for that function _before_ you change it!

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware of unit tests.

Comment: Perhaps the author intended to account for filespecs such as "..\filename" ?